# Add multiple Prices in Stripe while adding discount to only one item

Tags: javascript, express, stripe-payments

I have a problem, I want to charge two different prices while adding discount to only one of them.

The price where I want to add a discount is a subscription while the other one is one-time payment.

I am using ExpressJS with Typescript on my backend application.

I have searched a lot and found a few solutions but none were helpful for my case. I understand its a very specific case.

The only major thing that I have found was:

`const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({ customer: CUSTOMER_ID, items: [ { price: RECURRING_PRICE_ID, }, ], … add_invoice_items: [{ price: ONE_TIME_PRICE_ID, }] })`

But if I add the discount it will be applied to both of the prices as stripe generates only 1 invoice for it.

Appreciaate your help*your text*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way to fix this is to create a coupon that doesn't apply to the one-time product by setting `applies_to.products` list when [creating](https://stripe.com/docs/api/coupons/create#create_coupon-applies_to-products) the coupon